# iOS CoreData: "Data Model Version Compiler" error

Tags: ios, git, core-data, github

I created a data model file "ChatModel.xcdatamodeld" in my project. Then I merged branches on github. There're conflicts in "project.pbxproj". I fixed them. Then the error happened:

> "/Users/mac/zhongqing-ios/Zhongqing/Zhongqing/Model/ChatModel.xcdatamodeld: Could not create bundle folder for versioned model at '/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zhongqing-chngcirectbawjenegkxtgdfgoux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Zhongqing.app/ChatModel.momd'".
>
> "/Users/mac/zhongqing-ios/Zhongqing/ChatModel.xcdatamodeld: Unable to write VersionInfo.plist for versioned model at '/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zhongqing-chngcirectbawjenegkxtgdfgoux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Zhongqing.app/ChatModel.momd'".

Each time I have to delete the Derived Data so that the project can be run.
And then the error happen again.

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving, along with any other useful information that might help someone solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I cannot post images.... I included the errors now..

Comment: Are you able to edit the data model? It sounds like Xcode thinks the model file is corrupt, which would suggest that git's merging did not result in a useable file.

Answer (score 1):

Although some files are readable they should be treated like binary files. `.pbxproj`files are good example.

From [pro-git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files)

> Some files look like text files but for all intents and purposes are to be treated as binary data. For instance, Xcode projects on the Mac contain a file that ends in .pbxproj, which is basically a JSON (plain text javascript data format) dataset written out to disk by the IDE that records your build settings and so on. Although it’s technically a text file, because it’s all ASCII, you don’t want to treat it as such because it’s really a lightweight database — you can’t merge the contents if two people changed it, and diffs generally aren’t helpful. The file is meant to be consumed by a machine. In essence, you want to treat it like a binary file.