# Data model version error

Tags: ios, build, compiler-errors, data-modeling

I can't compile my project on Xcode now for some reason this 2errors data model version keeps poping up. I followed few fixes.

1. Delete the derivedData from Xcode directories
2. Disable MOMC from build setting
3. Reset ios emulator

Nothing is working I wasted 2hours trying to just build this projects which was working yesterday. Please help what should I do to build smoothly?

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error message it is displaying?

Comment: See the attached screenshot in the questions. I totally don't know what to do to just get the project building as it was yesterday.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901548/ios-coredata-data-model-version-compiler-error. Take a look at this.

Comment: Thanks I fixe deleted the two mystore